# XML parsing using LINQ to XML: Multiple descendants with same name

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

I am new to XML parsing using LINQ. I have the below XML:

```
<TEAM Action="abcd" TeamID="1234">
    <INST InstID="10001" />
    <TERM Label="abc" Desc="" Default="" Type="string">Non</TERM>
    <A>
      <NOTE Label="a">U</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="b">69537f</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="c">Po</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="d">f59/NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="e">2014</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="f">Non</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="g">Bilateral</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="h">Jo</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="i">602</NOTE>
   </A>
  </TEAM>

  <TEAM Action="abcdefg" TeamID="2345">
    <INST InstID="10003" />
    <TERM Label="abc" Desc="" Default="" Type="string">Non</TERM>
    <A>
      <NOTE Label="a">U</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="b">69537f</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="c">Po</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="d">f59/NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="e">2014</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="f">Non</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="g">Simple</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="h">Jo</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="i">602</NOTE>
   </A>
  </TEAM>
```

I am trying to write a query which returns all the teams where the value of NOTE element having label=g is Bilateral.
Any help is much appriciated.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Hey Tim. I was trying to it without using lambda expression. As i told you, i am a complete novice in xml parsing and linq queries. Your help is highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, the `xml` you give out is wrong, it should be

```
<TEAM Action="abcd" TeamID="1234">
    <INST InstID="10001" />
    <TERM Label="abc" Desc="" Default="" Type="string">Non</TERM>
    <A>
      <NOTE Label="a">U</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="b">69537f</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="c">Po</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="d">f59</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="e">2014</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="f">Non</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="g">Bilateral</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="h">Jo</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="i">602</NOTE>
   </A>
  </TEAM>

  <TEAM Action="abcdefg" TeamID="2345">
    <INST InstID="10003" />
    <TERM Label="abc" Desc="" Default="" Type="string">Non</TERM>
    <A>
      <NOTE Label="a">U</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="b">69537f</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="c">Po</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="d">f59</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="e">2014</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="f">Non</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="g">Simple</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="h">Jo</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="i">602</NOTE>
   </A>
  </TEAM>
```

then what you need is :

```
var xml=XDocument.Load("d:\\test.xml");
var list=xml.Descendants("TEAM")
            .Where(x=>x.Element("A").Elements("NOTE")
                       .Any(n=>n.Attribute("Label").Value=="g" && n.Value=="Bilateral"));
```